# Is there a way to save file colors

Tags: release-juno, system-installation

I liked very much the way you can colorize your files and folders, but I am thinking about reinstalling elementary OS. Is there some file I can copy to keep the colors after installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found out how to do it:

The file is in `~/.config/marlin/marlin.db`